# How to get list of open posix shared memory segments in FreeBSD

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, freebsd

In linux I can get the list of opened posix shared memory segments by getting */dev/shm* directory listing.

How do I programmatically get list of all opened posix shared memory segments in FreeBSD?
Assuming segments opened with `shm_open()` and I don't know even a part of a name that was used as a first argument of `shm_open()`.

Comment: from command line, `ipcs -m` returns the list of shared memory segments in use.

Comment: No. ipcs -m is for system V shared memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  See the comment in /sys/kern/uipc_shm.c:

```
 * TODO:
 *
 * (2) Need to export data to a userland tool via a sysctl.  Should ipcs(1)
 *     and ipcrm(1) be expanded or should new tools to manage both POSIX
 *     kernel semaphores and POSIX shared memory be written?
 *
 * (3) Add support for this file type to fstat(1).
```

Comment: If I run `ls -l /dev/shm/` on my Linux system (2.6.32) I can see the shared memory segments and their corresponding sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [posixshmcontrol](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=posixshmcontrol&sektion=1&format=html) utility.

Comment: Is there actually such a thing?  A search in several package managers with several variations of that name came up with nothing.  Since this package is for FreeBSD and the author of this question was specifically looking a Linux solution the answer is intersting but not useful.